# Getting Error Of Undefined Variable "data" php Codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I am updating table taking id in url which is auto increment.. i am also defiend a variable data in controller that is $data['**data**']=$this->articlesmodel->find_data($art_id); and this varible passing to view that is $this->load->view('admin/edit',$data); 
and in view at form open i called the variable id**}",['class'=>'form-horizontal']);?>
but the error occure that the $data is undefiend.

this is view code

```
<?php  echo form_open("admin/update_data/{$data->id}",['class'=>'form-horizontal']);?>
```

This is controller code

```
public function edit_data($art_id)
{
 $this->load->helper('form');
  $this->load->model('articlesmodel');
  $data['data']=$this->articlesmodel->find_data($art_id);
   $this->load->view('admin/edit',$data);

    }
```

This is Model Code

```
public function update_data($art_id, Array $data )
  {

       return $this->db
                   ->where('id',$art_id)
                   ->update('data',$data);


   }
```

Comment: $data is undefined in view or in update_data? If first one, are you sure that find_data returns object? var_dump $data before passing to view.

Comment: $data is undefined in view.  and here is the find_data function in model         public function find_data($art_id)
{

$q=$this->db->select(['id','username','fname','lname','email','contact','address','password','rolemodel_id'])
         ->where('id',$art_id)
         ->get('data');
         return $q->row();
}

Comment: paste var_dump($data) from controller (or just part of it with structure).

Comment: 1. Your form is trying to call your model, that isn't going to work.
2. Where does the parameter in your controller function $art_id come from? Controllers don't usually have parameters in codeigniter